# "What" vs "what kind of"

Tags: comparisons

So, I've read that questions "what kind of" are about characteristics:

"What kind of game is it? - It's an exciting game." **But** "What game is it? - It's Warcraft."

**Is it right?**

But what about "What (kind of) key is on the table?" - "It's my key".

1. Should I use "What key..." or "What kind of key..."?
2. Have I to use "the" before "key": "What (kind of) the key..."
3. Is it correct to answer such questions as "What (kind of)..." by "It's my, his..."

Comment: If you're looking for the owner of the keys, ask, "*Whose* key ...?" As for your second question, never use "What ... the key".

Comment: I don't know who is owner and I don't know what door can be opened by this key. So the matter is not in "whose is this key"

Comment: "Whose key ..." was a comment on your third question (maybe also your first question). If you're expecting a response of "It's my, his ...", you'd use "whose". To answer question 3 as stated, "What kind of ..." expects a response along the lines of copper / steel / old fashioned / etc. (Recall, *people are who not what*.) "What key ..." sounds like it's asking for the thing it opens - e.g. house key, car key.

Comment: @ Lawrence "What key ..." sounds like it's asking for the thing it opens - e.g. house key, car key. - it's that I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @Lawrence So the last question, is it correct: "What apple is it?" - "It's for you."

Comment: I've included your last question in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "What [kind of] key is on the table?"

Q1

In the question under discussion, "What kind of ..." is asking for properties of the key, and you can expect these kinds of answers: small key, steel key, old-fashioned key, etc.

Without the words "kind of", the question is a little awkward, though it can be understood to ask what the key opens: house key, car key. The question could be improved by changing it to "Which key is on the table?". However, this simply asks for something to distinguish the specified key from any other key within the relevant context. Answers could then be wide-ranging: blue key (not red key), house key (not car key), my key (not someone else's), etc.

Q2

You should never use "What kind of *the* key ...". The word "key" in this context is the general category for which you are seeking the specific *kind*. You should be able to take a typical answer (e.g. steel) and use it to qualify the category. *A steel key* makes sense; *a steel the key* doesn't.

You should also never use "What the key ..." - this is not grammatical and gets pretty close to the form of an expletive.

Q3

The simple constructs are "What is it?" and "Whose is it?". You use *what* if you are want to know more about *it*, and you use *whose* if you want to know the person to whom *it* belongs.

Question from the comments:

> "What apple is it?" - "It's for you."

This response doesn't properly answer the question. This question could be answered by the variety of the apple: granny smith apple, fuji apple, McIntosh apple, etc.

If you want "It's for you" as an answer, ask, "Who is it for?".

Comment: Now everything is clear. So: "What money is this?" "These are dollars". Right?

Comment: In conversation and with a shared context, that Question-Answer pair makes sense, though "What *type of* money ..." sounds better with that answer. If you keep the question "What money is this?", some answers more consistent with the question are of the form "This is [lunch / pocket / rent / etc] money."

Comment: @AlexeyMurzin If this answers your question, please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I didn't know about this button. :) I've marked it. So one more question: "What kind of pen is this?" - "This is a ball pen" or "This is ball pen". Guess it has to be used "a ball pen". And is it normal: "What type of pen are they?" - "They are  ball pens" ?

Comment: Yes, you need *a* in *This is a ball pen*. The last one is fine, though you need to be consistent with the singular or with the plural form, e.g. "pen*s* are".

Comment: Yes, yes.... it was automatically "What type of penS are..." That's all. Thank you very much.